# Адаптировать iframe под мобильную версию

Tags: iframe

Нашел один полезный информер который к сожелению не подходит для мобильной версии, а именно потому что даже при модификации ширины к примеру width:100%,  в ширину мобильного экрана не входит табло с временем.

Задача состояла в том, чтобы убрать сколл, и адапатировать таблицу под моб версию без каких либо скролов.

**Код информера**

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); overflow: hidden; border: 0; width: 700px; height: 303px;" src="https://rasp.yandex.ru/informers/station/2000001/?type=schedule"></iframe>
```

Возможно ли это ? и какие есть альтернативные или похожие решения, к примеру парсинг данных с информера или какие есть варианты...

Answer (score 0):

Измени код информера на такой:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border: 0; width: 100%; height: 303px;" src="https://rasp.yandex.ru/informers/station/2000001/?type=schedule"></iframe>
```

И будет тебе счастье:) у него по умолчанию стояло 700px ширина.

Comment: Не будет ! :) читайте внимательно

Comment: У меня все адаптировано,  я с телефона зашел. На jsFiddle..

Comment: Время у вас тоже видно ? без скрола

Comment: Да, только если экран сделать сильно маленьким то уже скрол появляеться. Но по другому никак. Это вёрстка самого rasp.yandex и вы на нее никак не повлияете, это вполне нормально и по другому вы никак не сделаете.

Comment: Сильно маленьким это каким ?  так как в firefox я выбираю все девайсы, и до 400x время нормально не видно, только на планшетах и лаптопах, нормально в плане видно толко первый две цифры.. или вообще не видно и появляется скролл

Comment: Я открываю ссылку на телефоне, ту которую вы даете,  и они на своем сайте используют масштабирование, что говорит о том что у них не поддерживаються телефонные разрешения нормально. Так что увы но вы не сможете изменить их код в любом случае.

Comment: Плохо, очень плохо, так как сервис хорош, работает на дескопах лаптопах хорошо, а вот если моб - это проблема, его нужно тогда скрывать, но это не решение. Есть какие нибудь альтернативные решения такой задачи ?

Comment: Ну либо написать им конкретно с этим вопросом, либо выбрать другой сервис. Но я не понимаю почему вы так переживаете, потому что то, что время немного не влазит и нужно проскролить на разширениях ниже 400 px нормальная практика. По другому данные никак не врезут в ширину экрана. Помогло бы уменьшение размера шрифтов, но вы никак не повлияете на их сайт. Возможно стоит все же написать им в поддержку с этим вопосом.